# Google Chrome doesn't work on startup

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have Google Chrome pinned to the taskbar on windows 7 32bit. It was working fine, but, yesterday, upon starting up the computer, it wouldn't work. The browser window was just a light blue and all the extension icons were gone. I went into the chrome install folder and found old_chrome.exe and chrome.exe. When opening old_chrome, the same thing happens, but when opening just chrome.exe, everything is normal. I unpinned chrome from the taskbar, opened chrome.exe, and pinned that to the taskbar and it was working fine. It did the same thing this morning though.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus installed?

Comment: @criziot, Yes, eset.

Comment: Forget, `old_chrome.exe` is usualy safe. I don't have time right now to help you, but a search for `old_chrome.exe` in google may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is happening to a lot of people in the last couple days - see http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chrome/old_chrome/chrome/mrnDeD1BrUM/_fgO-ugzPlUJ

One person there says the following:

> ok so i managed to sort this out finally :D.I fully uninstalled chrome from my computer i also removed a program on my computer call yontoo layers runtime (unsure if that is required but mentioned it because i did it).
>   i then download this version of chrome from
>
> http://www.afterdawn.com/software/network/browsers/google_chrome_dev.cfm
>
> and bingo it works thank god as not a big fan of other browsers :D

Might want to try that out.